# ubuntu packages and Advance Package Manager

Tags: package-management

I am new to Linux, but used windows before. I have not used command line more. I googled about `apt` and `dpkg` and came to know they are related to something called package. 
What is meant by package here?Is executable application, also called as a package?.

With little programming experience, I know that package is a group of some program files

What it actually is referring to when it says package?

For example, apt (Advance Package Tool)? What is packed in the advance package tool?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between a package and a software in ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/630444/what-is-the-difference-between-a-package-and-a-software-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apt is the program that lets you search/download/install/remove/manipulate deb-format packages, of which many thousands are available.

A *package* is a compressed archive containing a group of files. Sometimes the files are an application (firefox), sometimes a library, sometimes documentation, sometimes the Linux kernel etc. Your Ubuntu system is made up of thousands of installed packages already...*and nothing else*. Many packages depend upon having other packages installed in order to work. Untangling such dependencies is a big part of apt's job.

Apt does not contain any packages itself. That would make it much too large. Instead, apt downloads *package metadata* from the online Ubuntu Repositories.

When you ask apt to search for a package (`apt search firefox`), you are searching that local cache of metadata.

When you ask apt to install a package (`sudo apt install firefox`), apt does ALL the downloading and installing for you. That's right -- one command does *both* for ALL the packages necessary to make `firefox` work.

Apt does NOT handle non-deb packages. Apt cannot help you with Snaps, AppImages, Flatpaks, etc. Apt cannot help you with raw source code, zipfiles, self-compiled software, or self-written scripts.

- See https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/apt.html for what apt is and how to use it.
- See http://packages.ubuntu.com for the packages available in the Ubuntu Repositories.
- Advice: As a new Ubuntu User, DO NOT DOWNLOAD SOFTWARE YOURSELF. Use Apt or Ubuntu Software until you understand the pitfalls of how an Ubuntu system is different from a Windows system.

Answer (score 1):

`dpkg`  is the **Linux Debian packages manager**. When you use the `apt` command to install a package, `apt` will invoke the `dpkg` program to install or remove applications while including additional functions `dpkg` doesn’t like dependency resolution. The program `dpkg` can be used to install or remove programs and some other related things.

Packages contain all of the files necessary to implement a set of related commands or features. For Ubuntu, they usually have the `.deb` extension. Since you have used Windows, you can think the `.deb` packages as `.exe` or `.msi` files.

There are some tools that help us to help us install these packages. One of these tools is `apt` which used to install packages.